# Delete indentation on a HTML list

Tags: css, indentation

I am working on a dynamic HTML list for a mobile website. The basic concept works, but I would like to remove the spacing on the side of the list. I have tried with `margin-left` and `padding-left`, but it still doesn't work.

Example :

```
/* Now */
    List1
    List2
    List3

/* And I want */
List1
List2
List3
```

Comment: Try to remove le `padding`/`margin` from the `ul` not from the `li`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to remove the `padding` from the list items' container (`ul`, `ol` or `menu`):

```
ul {
    padding-left:0;
}
```

Comment: With ul{padding-left:0;} it works, I don't know why I've not try it... Thanks guys !

Answer (score 1):

Computed style on Safari for an `<ul>`

```
display: block;
font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Arial, Helvetica;
font-size: 12px;
height: 30px;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-bottom: 12px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 12px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
width: 795px;
```

For the `<li>` (as you can see, mostly inherited from the parent `<ul>`)

```
display: list-item;
font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Arial, Helvetica;
font-size: 12px;
height: 15px;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
text-align: -webkit-auto;
width: 795px;
```

Padding-left (inherrited too);

```
padding-left: 40px;
```

set it to something lower:

```
padding-left: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the padding from the ul:

```
  ul {padding-left:0}
```

I guess this probably means you haven't setup a css reset as well, put this in at the top of your css file:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: I would't recommend using a CSS reset style in each project you do. Many designers are commonly used to the fact that (when they work with basic HTML) that for example `<h#>` tags have certain spatial behavior. Removing this might cause unwanted results between programmers in designers. Just saying :). The `padding-left` part would be enough for this question.

Comment: I use one in every project I do. There is ofcourse a standard value for every element/rule, but this varies from browser to browser. I would rather not trust my styles to the default of what could be one of any number of browsers when the styles can easily be set.

Comment: A little more info on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/is-it-ok-to-use-a-css-reset-stylesheet